# Order list by date and sequence number

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have been learning C# (I am relatively new) and I have a list of input files consisting file naming format like "inputFile_dateSequence_sequenceNumber.xml". The code that I am using to sort the file lists in ascending order is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] inputfiles = { "inputFile_2020-04-10_1.xml", 
                               "inputFile_2020-04-10_2.xml", 
                               "inputFile_2020-04-10_4.xml",
                               "inputFile_2020-04-10_3.xml", 
                               "inputFile_2020-04-10_10.xml",
                               "inputFile_2020-05-10_1.xml",
                               "inputFile_2020-05-10_2.xml",
                               "inputFile_2020-05-10_10.xml",
                               "inputFile_2020-05-10_11.xml" };
        
        
        List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
        
        foreach (string s in inputfiles)
        {
            string bz = s.Split('.')[0];
            stringList.Add(bz);
        }
        
        string[] Separator = new string[] { "_" };
        var sortedList = stringList.OrderBy(i => i).ThenBy(s => int.Parse(s.Split(Separator, StringSplitOptions.None)[2])).ToList();
        
        foreach (string i in sortedList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        
    }

}
```

But in ascending order, I am getting output as below:

```
inputFile_2020-04-10_1
inputFile_2020-04-10_10
inputFile_2020-04-10_2
inputFile_2020-04-10_3
inputFile_2020-04-10_4
inputFile_2020-05-10_1
inputFile_2020-05-10_10
inputFile_2020-05-10_11
inputFile_2020-05-10_2
```

but my desired output is like below:

```
inputFile_2020-04-10_1.xml 
inputFile_2020-04-10_2.xml
inputFile_2020-04-10_3.xml
inputFile_2020-04-10_4.xml
inputFile_2020-04-10_10.xml
inputFile_2020-05-10_1.xml
inputFile_2020-05-10_2.xml
inputFile_2020-05-10_10.xml
inputFile_2020-05-10_11.xml
```

What modification should the code need in order to get the output like this?

Comment: Do not use Split('.')[0] to get the FileName without extension. Use `Path.GetFilenameWithoutExtension`

Comment: `s.Split(Separator, StringSplitOptions.None)[2]` can be just `Split('_')` - None is the default for arg 2

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```cs
var sortedList = stringList
    .OrderBy(s => s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf('_')))            // sort by inputFile_dateSequence
    .ThenBy(s => int.Parse(s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf('_') + 1))) // sort by sequenceNumber as integer
    .ToList();
```

**Update**. If you want to preserve file extension, you can use the following:

```cs
List<string> sortedList = inputfiles
    .Select(s =>
    {
        int nameSeparator = s.LastIndexOf('_');
        int extSeparator = s.LastIndexOf('.');
        
        return new
        {
            FullName = s,
            BaseName = s.Substring(0, nameSeparator),
            Sequence = int.Parse(s.Substring(nameSeparator + 1, extSeparator - nameSeparator - 1)),
            Extension = s.Substring(extSeparator + 1)
        };
    })
    .OrderBy(f => f.BaseName)  // sort by inputFile_dateSequence
    .ThenBy(f => f.Sequence)   // sort by sequenceNumber
    .ThenBy(f => f.Extension)  // sort by file extension
    .Select(f => f.FullName)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Hello. Wow. That really is a effective one. Thank you very much. This really works. I think I forgot to add .xml in the desired output field. How can I achieve that after sorting? @ruslan.gilmutdinov

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve your need by using regex:

```
var sortedList= stringList.OrderBy(x => Regex.Replace(x, @"\d+", m => m.Value.PadLeft(10, '0')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Loads of ways to solve this, as you can see...

You can order first by just the date part of the name, then by the length of the name string, so smaller numbers like 1, 7 sort before longer numbers like 10, 17.. then by the name itself

```
.OrderBy(x => x.Remove(20))
  .ThenBy(x=>x.Length)
  .ThenBy(x=>x)
```

Perhaps though you'd parse the entire thing:

```
class MyFile{
  string FullName {get;set;}
  string Name {get;set;}
  DateTime Date {get;set;}
  int Num {get;set;}

  MyFile(string fullname){
    var bits = Path.GetFilenameWithoutExtension( fullname).Split('_');

    FullName = FullName;
    Name = bits[0];
    Date = DateTime.Parse(bits[1]);
    Num = int.Parse(bits[2]);
  }
```

Then

```
var parsed = inputfiles.Select(x => new MyFile(x));
```

Now you can OrderBy that:

```
parsed.OrderBy(m => m.Date).ThenBy(m => m.Num);
```

Try to avoid doing everything at some base level of string/int primitive; this is OO programming!

Answer (score 0):

Using DataTable and LinQ may help you to do the task done easier.

Below is the code with DataTable that generate your desire output

```
 public static void Main()
    {
        string[] inputfiles = { "inputFile_2020-04-10_1.xml",
                           "inputFile_2020-04-10_2.xml",
                           "inputFile_2020-04-10_4.xml",
                           "inputFile_2020-04-10_3.xml",
                           "inputFile_2020-04-10_10.xml",
                           "inputFile_2020-05-10_1.xml",
                           "inputFile_2020-05-10_2.xml",
                           "inputFile_2020-05-10_10.xml",
                           "inputFile_2020-05-10_11.xml" };

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("filename", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));
        dt.Columns.Add("sequence", typeof(int));

        foreach (string s in inputfiles)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = s;
            dr[1] = Convert.ToDateTime(s.Split('_')[1]);
            dr[2] = Convert.ToInt32(s.Split('_')[2].Split('.')[0]);
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        DataTable sortedDT = dt.AsEnumerable()
             .OrderBy(r => r.Field<DateTime>("date"))
             .ThenBy(r => r.Field<int>("sequence"))
             .CopyToDataTable();

        foreach (DataRow dr in sortedDT.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dr[0]);
        }
    }
```

Output:

[image]